# Pick up files from multiple location using camel FTP

Tags: apache-camel

i have a situation i need to pick up files from two different location using camel FTP.

currently my code is

try {

```
        from(format("sftp://%s@%s:22/../../..%s?password=%s&delete=true", ftpUserName, ftpServer, responsePath, ftpPassword ))
                .filter(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".PDF"))
                .to(format("sftp://%s@%s:22/../../..%s/processed?password=%s", ftpUserName, ftpServer, responsePath, ftpPassword))
                .process(documentProcessor)
               /*.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, (org.slf4j.Logger) logger, "Download file ${file:name} complete.")*/
                /*.to(downloadLocation)*/;
        /*.to(format("smtp://relay.us.signintra.com?to=%s&from=noreply@dbschenker.com&subject=GTM response from cisco", emailTo))*/
        ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is picking up the file that is mentioned in the application.properties files. How can i do this to puck up files from multile locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple FTP consumer routes and forward the message to shared direct-endpoint.

**Example:**

```java
from("ftp:{{target.host}}:{{ftp.port}}/{{target.path1}}...")
    .routeId("PollForFilesInPath1")
    .to("direct:handleFileFromFTP");

from("ftp:{{target.host}}:{{ftp.port}}/{{target.path2}}...")
    .routeId("PollForFilesInPath2")
    .to("direct:handleFileFromFTP");

from("direct:handleFileFromFTP")
    .routeId("handleFileFromFTP")
    .log("file received from ftp: ${headers.CamelFileName }")
    // Do stuff with the file
```

If you need to call 2 FTP consumer endpoints from single route you can use [poll-enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html).